# How to join the multiple row values from jTable into one row of mysql

Tags: java, jtable

So i have a jframe that looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eULbN.png]

everytime i send the data to my database it creates 3 rows which exactly look like this (please see attached image for reference)

Purchase Order | Name | Item_ID | Item_Name | Item_price | Item_Stock | Total

1 | Marc | 2 | 9V Battery | 90.0 | 1 | 90.0

1 | Marc | 3 | Stranded Wire | 10.0 | 1 | 10.0

1 | Marc | 4 | Solid Wire | 12.0 | 1 | 12.0

**What i want to do is merge the value of this three rows and send this to database like this using java**

1 | Marc | 2,3,4 | 9V Battery, Stranded Wire, Solid Wire | 90.0,10.0,12.0 | 1,1,1 | 90.0,10.0,12.0

is that even possible?? this is my first time to ask so pardon me if i make mistakes

this is my current code

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") ; 
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbms?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root",""); 
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String PurchOrder = JL_POrder.getText();
            String Name = JL_Name.getText();

            TableModel model = jTable3.getModel();
            for(int j=0;j<model.getRowCount();j++)
            {

            String Item_ID=jTable3.getValueAt(j, 0).toString();
            String Item_Name=jTable3.getValueAt(j, 1).toString();
            String Item_price=jTable3.getValueAt(j, 2).toString();
            String Item_Stock=jTable3.getValueAt(j, 3).toString();
            String Total = jTable3.getValueAt(j, 4).toString();


           st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `customer_order_details` (`Purchase Order`, `Name`, `Item_ID`, `Item_Name`, `Item_price`, `Item_Stock`, `Total`) VALUES ('"+PurchOrder+"','"+Name+"','"+Item_ID+"','"+Item_Name+"','"+Item_price+"','"+Item_Stock+"','"+Total+"')");


        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Checkout");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Anything is possible but kind of defeats the purpose of using a database. Each column in the database should store 1 data item, not 3 items separated by commas. So you should have 3 rows in the database. The purchase order and the item id would be the unique keys which would allow you to have 1 or more rows for each purchase order.

Comment: See also: RDBMS normalization.  Then isolate how the data is persisted from how the user interacts with it.

Comment: hey @camickr well the problem is the column purchase order is set to be a primary key so that will be a problem

Comment: `order is set to be a primary key so that will be a problem` - then that is the problem you should be fixing. In any case, I'm still not sure what your question is. If you know how to update a data base with a String for a column then you can update a dabase with a string that contains data separated with commas. A String is a String.